Can I use a QRC file from a module in my qt project?
I've made a small QT library/module that houses some common QML and C++ functionality between various projects I've made. I'd also like to use this library to house various common resources (such as images of logos).
Is this possible? Maybe with cmake? If so, how can I accomplish it?
I'm using Qt 6.7.0 with CMake.
SimpleLib - CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(SimpleLib VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

# STATIC causes SimpleLib_resources_1 and SimpleLib_resources_2 to appear in QtCreator source tree.
qt_add_library(SimpleLib STATIC)
qt_add_qml_module(SimpleLib
    URI SimpleLib
    VERSION 1.0
    NO_PLUGIN
    RESOURCES SimpleLibResources.qrc
)

target_link_libraries(SimpleLib
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
)

target_include_directories(SimpleLib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS SimpleLib
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

ExampleProject - CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(ExampleProject VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.4 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick)

qt_standard_project_setup()

#WIN32 Hides Console Window (When Running Direct)
qt_add_executable(ExampleProject WIN32
    main.cpp
)

qt_add_qml_module(ExampleProject
    URI ExampleProject
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
    RESOURCES ExampleProjectResources.qrc
)

target_link_libraries(ExampleProject
   PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
   SimpleLib
)

target_include_directories(ExampleProject
   PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../SimpleLib")

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS ExampleProject
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

ExampleProject - Main.qml
import QtQuick
import SimpleLib 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        // SimpleLibLogo is contained in SimpleLibResources.qrc, but it's not working.
        source: "Images/SimpleLibLogo.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}


If you use Qt Designer (and AFAIK, Creator) you can use the resource browser and add anything you want to the QRC file. Check the Qt Resource System documentation.

@musicamante yes, but I want to use a resource file from another Qt module, which isn't working (as shown in my code).
